# Why does program crash for dereferencing pointer to char by using '%s'?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am learning c, a beginner, can anybody please make me understood which concept am I missing?
And thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[10];
    s[0]='A';
    s[1]='B';
    s[2]='\0';
    char *p;
    int i;

    p=s;


    printf("%c\n", *p); //It's ok.


    printf("%s", *p); // or *s...what's wrong here,why does program crash?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because it is expecting pointer and not it's dereferenced value..

Comment: `%s` expects a `char *`, not a `char`.

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings.  A good compiler would have warned about  `char *p; ... printf("%s", *p);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
printf("%s", *p);
```

to

```
printf("%s", p);
```

The reason why is that `%s` is expecting a pointer, and `*p` is the dereferenced value at `p`, aka the char value at `p[0]`.

If this doesn't make sense, picture why `printf("%c\n", *p)` works. `*p` is the same as `p[0]`, which is the same as `s[0]` since `p` points to `s`. Because `s[0]` is a `char`, `%c` works here because it is expecting a `char`. But `%s` on the other hand expects `char *`.

Comment: Thanks, I have understood now, as '%s' expects char * !

Comment: @Sumon no problem, if you found the answer helpful then don't forget to upvote or accept the answer. Good luck coding!

Comment: this is my first question here. And got solved quickly. It's cool! :)

Comment: @Sumon To get your question solved, even quicker, enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @Chris your last edit is exactly what I am really searching for, perfect explanation to me as a newbie, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You want `printf("%s", p)`.  Don't dereference the pointer.